# Free media center PC software which runs on Windows XP

Tags: windows, recording, tuner-card, media-center

Is there something which may:

- Play music, at the very least in MP3-format
- Play video in various codec's
- Helps in recording video of shows from TV through a TV-in card
- Helps in organizing music and videos
- Works with a keyboard and mouse

Additional pluses are:

- If it also is possible to browse the web through it, or at least start the web browser
- Has some games. Maybe through MAME or some other emulation like SNES or something.
- If it's also possible to control it through a game pad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Media Poral](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/) got plugins, one where it's possible to start other apps, like browser, emulator/games etc. Can do (i think all) your reqeirments and maybe more. Can also handle timeshifting (right word?) and pause the tv-program you are watching etc.

As grapefrukt mentiond it's not trivial to setup, but probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

[XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) (the software formerly known as Xbox Media Center) can do most of your requirements except for the recording. 
[MediaPortal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/) is it's bigger and slightly wonkier relative, it can do recording but is in my opinion a bit trickier to set up.

Comment: XBMC is pretty fantastic.

Comment: XBMC kicks ass. Also, as a nitpick, it is no longer called "Xbox Media Center". They did away with that when they started designing their builds explicitly for Ubuntu, and now it's just XBMC.

Comment: fixed it!

Comment: Just be aware recent versions need a moderately recent video card with good OpenGL support.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [Tversity](http://tversity.com/download/features/). I don't think it allows TV recording, but it excels at transcoding on-the-fly and streaming to UPnP AV/DLNA devices. Then there's [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/), and [Boxee](http://www.boxee.tv/homepage/) (an XBMC fork).

Look through this Lifehacker article for [a roundup of media centre options](http://lifehacker.com/5103464/five-best-media-center-applications). There's a separate [roundup of DVR applications](http://lifehacker.com/5128408/six-best-dvr-applications) for your TV-watching needs, with some apps featuring in both lists.

Answer (score 4):

MediaPortal has been my best choice so far, and has worked well for most all of my uses. Unlike some of the other responses, I found it fairly easily to set up and almost negligible to maintain. I primarily use it to watch recorded or downloaded TV shows and movies, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

[GBPVR](http://www.gbpvr.com/) is a free pvr for windows. It allows you to record TV shows and play them back using a TV Tuner card. It also allows you to view photos and play MP3s back using a single interface. In addition it allows for plugins. More information is available at the link at the beginning of the answer.